# CAEmitterLayer emitter in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quartz-core

I am developing an app for IPhone 5+ and IOS 8.
My plan is to use a CAEmitterLayer as described in  Ray Wenderlich tutorial below [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial)

Thing is my view has an embedded collection view consisting of custom cells. The emitter display is shown in the background. If i try to customise the UICollectionview object as per the tutorial; then the emitter is displayed behind the cells.

The expected result is to have the emitter is shown in front of the cells, not behind.

I have tried to bring the tutorial customisation to the customised UICollectionViewCell with no result; then i thought about adding a subview on the top but it starts intercepted the touch message from the whole collection view and cells.

Would you know how to proceed?

Comment: Can you insert your CAEmitterlayer into the collectionView at the index of the bounds of the number of sublayers? Something like this? `[self.collectionView.layer insertSublayer:emitterLayer atIndex:self.collectionView.layer.subLayers.count];`

Comment: the principle was indeed to add it to the sublayer. Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0):

To have the emitter shown in front of the cell, adding it to the sublayer works:

```
[(CAEmitterLayer *)self.layer addSublayer: cursorEmiter];
```

Works fine now !